# Expected Number of pairs of adjacent faces of a random cube.

Tags: probability, dice

A cube has each of its 6 faces wieh random number chosen independently and uniformly at random from 1~6.

What is the expected number of pairs of adjacent faces with numbers differ by 1?

And also roll the cube, let T denote the sum of the numbers on all the faces of the die, X be the score X(upward-facing number)
What is E(X|T)?

I don't actually see a way expect of counting the number of pairs from 1 to 12 or sth like that. Any Ideas?

Comment: Each face is adjacent to 4 others, and this doesn't change if you write different numbers on them. Do you mean adjacent pairs of faces with the same number written on them? And just to be clear, you're picking uniformly random _integers_ in the range 1 to 6, _including_ 1 and 6, right?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant the expected number of pairs of adjacent faces with number s differ by 1.

Comment: @Arthur Yes including 1 and 6. And the faces need numbers differ by 1.

Comment: @Henry Ye I did think of that. And there is not quite straight forward relations between the expected number and anything else. So I think the only way is give a try to 1 2 3 ... 12 pairs each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expectation is linear. Consider, for each of the 12 pairs of adjacent sides, the variable $X_n$ which is $1$ if pair $n$ are given numbers that differ by one and $0$ if they don't.

We have $X=\sum X_n$, and therefore $E(X)=\sum E(X_n)$. The right-hand side is not too difficult to calculate, as the twelve expectations are all equal. Even in the second problem, conditioned on the value of the top facing side, this is the way to go, where four of the $E(X_n\mid T)$ are distinct from the rest.

Comment: I kinda understand it. But I thought the linearity of Expectation is just something like E(ax+b)=aE(x)+b?

Comment: @WillG It is that, but it is also $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ no matter what the relationship between $X$ and $Y$, so long as all the expectations are finite

Comment: @Arthur Nice I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

That is really two questions.  Hints:

- For the first, consider each edge: what is the probability an edge has its two adjacent faces with the desired relationship? How many edges are there?
- For the second, you can use a symmetry/exchangeability argument: given $T$, each face has the same expected value, and you know what these faces add up to.

Comment: For the first, I did think of that before. But even I think of each edge, they have to form a cube all together? So there will be some restriction for choosing number of 12 of them, and I can't actually figure out what that restriction is

Comment: @WillG Thanks to linearity of expectation, you do not need to worry about any dependency between the different edges or faces

Comment: Okay... so that is how powerful the linearity is?